# How to fix the " 'str' object does not support item assignment " in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to replace the 'X' in a text file with random whole number and rewrite the list to a new file, but it stuck at that line and I'm not sure how to fix it.

I tried to remove the str() but it said it need a str

```py
def changex2num(fileName):
    file = open(fileName,'r+')
    table = []
    for line in file:
    #line=line.strip()
        table.append(line)  # add all text in the list
        for num in range(len(line)):
            [num] = line[num].replace('X', str(random.randint(0, 3)))
            table.append(line[num])  # replace x by random integer from the list

    writefile = input('which file you would like to write?')
    File = open(writefile,'w')  # open the target file to write
    for things in range(len(table)):
        for ele in range(len(table[things])):
            print(table[things][ele], end=' ')
            File.write(table[things][ele] + '\n')

fileName = input('enter the file you want to read') 
changex2num(fileName)
```

I expect the X will all be replaced to a number,but it give me an error.

Comment: `str` in python are immutable. Somewhere in your code, you are trying to change a specific position of a string. For example, suppose you have `my_str = "hello"`. One would think that by doing `my_str[0] = 'b'`, `my_str` would be `bello`. But this doesn't happen in python because strings are immutable. Then, the error you get is raised

Comment: You are also running into the issue where you are assuming every line in the file has an 'X'

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def changex2num(fileName):
        file = open(fileName,'r+')
        table = []
        buffer = ''

        for line in file:
            for c in line:
                if c == 'x':
                    c = str(random.randint(0, 3))
                buffer += c
            table.append(line)
            buffer = ''

        # and the rest of your code
        #...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def changex2num(fileName):
    file = open(fileName, 'r+')
    table = []
    for line in file:
        # line=line.strip()
        table.append(line)  # add all text in the list
        for num in range(len(line)):
            c = line.replace("x", str(random.randint(0, 3))) #I only changed this line 

    writefile = input('which file you would like to write?')
    File = open(writefile, 'w')  # open the target file to write
    for things in range(len(table)):
        for ele in range(len(table[things])):
            print(table[things][ele], end=' ')
            File.write(table[things][ele] + '\n')


fileName = input('enter the file you want to read')`enter code here`
changex2num(fileName)
```

## let me now if this is what you want

Comment: It does the replacement, and I changed the written part code to write file, but the replaced number line is under the original line, how do I delete the original line?